# Devise Rails 4 RSpec 3 - Validates email with regex ending by @grenoble-em.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, rspec

I am stuck trying to forbid user registering on devise without an email address ending by "@grenoble-em.com". What would be the validation to add in the use model ? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a regex for that, you can simply use [index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-index):

```
"good.mail@grenoble-em.com".index("@grenoble-em.com", -16)
```

where 16 is the position from the end of the string and the number of letters of the searched substring.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific on how to use it please, where should I put it etc cause I do not master it at all. Thank you so much